# /me/associated doesn't return meta sites anymore

Tags: bug, users, meta, api-v2.3

The [documentation of `/me/associated`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-associated-users) says:

> You can filter the network_users returned by this method with the `types` parameter. Specify, semicolon delimited, `main_site` or `meta_site` to filter by site.

However, [using the value `meta_site`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-associated-users#&types=meta_site&filter=!9_bDE.BDp) doesn't give any `items` (even though, for me, the `total` is shown as being 175, which is correct):

```
{
  "items": [],
  "has_more": false,
  "quota_max": 10000,
  "quota_remaining": 9993,
  "total": 175
}
```

[Not using the types parameter](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-associated-users#&filter=!9_bDE.BDp) gives a `total` of 177, which is indeed the number of *main* sites I have an account on (Meta Stack Exchange and Stack Apps don't have a Meta site, that's why this is 2 higher.) Using the value `main_site` also gives a `total` of 177. Here, the items (site accounts) *are* returned as expected.

This issue is perhaps related to [Meta sites in “Your Communities” display different reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317269/295232).

Comment: Now also on Meta.SE: [Associated users endpoint gives empty response for meta users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371659/295232)

Comment: API Version 2.3 still having this issue, can replicate with my account, [see my API call here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/associated-users#page=1&pagesize=60&ids=1895213&types=main_site%3Bmeta_site&filter=!2.E*KTn*l*W4jGP2jDVwz)